# Determine the tangent plane on this paraboloide

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

given a paraboloide $\frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}=\frac{z}{\gamma}$

The tangent on a point $(x_0,y_0)$ along the paraboloide is given by $(x,y,f(x_0,y_0) + \langle \nabla f (x_0,y_0), (x-x_0,y-y_0))$ correct? Where $f$ is given by $f(x,y)= \gamma (\frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2})$

I just want to know whether my thoughts are all correct so far? Or is there another procedure to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get the right answer if you do the routine way of finding the equation of the plane passing through a point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$ tangent to surface: $$S: \frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}-\frac{z}{\gamma}=0$$

Indeed, we have: $$\nabla S|_{P}=\left(\frac{2x_0}{\alpha^2},\frac{2y_0}{\beta^2},\frac{1}{-\gamma}\right)$$ and so the equation of that plane is:

$$(x-x_0)\left(\frac{2x_0}{\alpha^2}\right)+(y-y_0)\left(\frac{2y_0}{\beta^2}\right)+(z-z_0)\left(\frac{1}{-\gamma}\right)=0$$ Try to factor some terms to get that $f(x,y)$.